# Responsive vimeo in fancybox-2 - how to resize video when fancybox resizes

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, vimeo

I am unable to get the vimeo embedded iframe to resize properly when resizing the window, using fancybox (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

On sizing the window down Fancybox resizes fine, as does the embedded video (using the code below).

However, resize the window back up and the fancybox stays the same, as does the video.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/prng9/1/ - resize the result frame down then back up (The resizing down isn't perfect either to be honest - if anyone has any better ways please let me know - the code is based on this: http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)

This is the fancy box code I am using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var htmlcontent = "<html><body><div class='vimeo_embed'><iframe class='vimeo' src='//player.vimeo.com/video/47438073' width='500' height='281' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div></body></html>";

  jQuery.fancybox.open(
    {
        content: htmlcontent,
        type:'ajax',
        padding : 0,
        afterShow: function(current,previous) {
            var vid = jQuery('iframe.vimeo');
            var ht = vid.height();
            var wd = vid.width();
            vid.attr('data-aspectRatio', ht / wd)
                .width(wd)
                .height(ht)
                .removeAttr('width')
                .removeAttr('height');
            },
        onUpdate: function() {
            //should run when size or orientation is changed
            var vid = jQuery('iframe.vimeo');                               
            var newWidth = jQuery('.vimeo_embed').width();
            vid.width(newWidth).height(newWidth * vid.attr('data-aspectRatio'));
    }
  });  
});
```

Note: I know fancybox allows vimeo resizing if linking to the video directly - for example I could use http://player.vimeo.com/video/47438073 as the href, along with the media helper, and all would be fine.  However I have certain amount of access controls and tracking on video views so am using the videos embedded on other pages.  Hence the reason why I have included the html code in the sample above - this simulates the same environment.

Thanks.

Comment: Why you don't simply use fancybox media helper? http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples vimeo example (media helper) is fully responsive without further complications

Comment: To use the fancybox media helper I would need to link to vimeo.com/[video_id], which would A. expose the link to the public and B. open the vimeo page if JS is not enabled. Neither of which I would like to do.  The video needs to be embedded within my site as there is a certain amount of access control to the videos - they are not freely available.

Comment: You are exposing the video ID within the `htmlcontent` variable though.

Comment: I know, it's just a loose access control - not meant to be anything foolproof as it's not mission-critical :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JFK's answer got me thinking differently and I've figured out a way - set the link to the embedded video on site in the `href` of the `<a>` and add a data value within this element with the link to the vimeo player:

```
<a href="/link_on_site_to_embedded_video" data-href="//player.vimeo.com/video/47438073">Open fancybox</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a').fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    type: 'iframe',
    width: 640,
    height: 360,
    aspectRatio: true,
    scrolling: 'no',
    beforeLoad: function() {
        var url= $(this.element).data("href");
        this.href = url
    }
});
```

If the user has no Javascript enabled, they are taken to the embedded video page.

If they have Javascript enabled then the content is updated before it is loaded to show the vimeo video - and they will 'see' the embedded video link (eg if right click > copy link address or open in new tab).

This is exactly the behaviour I needed.

Of course as JFK points out it's not foolproof - they can still see the vimeo link in the code, but if anyone wishes to trawl the code they are welcome to it.

See here http://jsfiddle.net/BHfv8/

Comment: well, this doesn't answer your original question, which was `how to resize video when fancybox resizes`

Comment: This answer meets all requirements stated in the original question. You must read the entire question to give a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you were already wrapping the video inside an `iframe`, just let fancybox to do the job instead so you could rather do this :

```
var htmlcontent = "//player.vimeo.com/video/47438073";
$.fancybox.open({
    href: htmlcontent,
    padding: 0,
    type: 'iframe',
    width: 640, // or whatever
    height: 360,
    aspectRatio: true, // <== this keep your vimeo aspect ratio after resize
    scrolling: 'no'
});
```

See <kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jHkjS/)**</kbd>